# PMPI and otf2: linking C code in CPP program

Tags: c++, c, mpi

I have a CPP program which is generated by [wrap.py](https://github.com/LLNL/wrap). wrap.py is used to produce wrapper for MPI program. It redirects any normal MPI call to PMPI call for intercepting purposes in order to do e.g. performance analysis. Pls download the generated code [here](https://pastebin.com/9t0WPPpk). I use [otf2](https://silc.zih.tu-dresden.de/otf2-current/index.html) to trace MPI program.

To explain the code:

```
// test4.cpp
__attribute__((constructor)) void init(void)
{
  if(!is_init)
  {
    archive = OTF2_Archive_Open( "./",
                                 "ArchiveTest",
                                 OTF2_FILEMODE_WRITE,
                                 1024 * 1024 /* event chunk size */,
                                 4 * 1024 * 1024 /* def chunk size */,
                                 OTF2_SUBSTRATE_POSIX,
                                 OTF2_COMPRESSION_NONE );
    is_init = true;
  }
}

__attribute__((destructor))  void fini(void)
{
  if(is_init)
  {
    OTF2_Archive_Close( archive );
    is_init = false;
  }
}
```

I am going to compile the code into an .so file. So when it's imported the `constructor` would be called; when the .so gets detached, the `destructor` is called.

According to the official doc of otf2[here](https://silc.zih.tu-dresden.de/otf2-current/group__usage__writing__mpi.html), I compile the program:

```
mpic++ -fpic -c `otf2-config --cflags` -o test4.o test4.cpp
mpic++ -shared -o libtest4.so `otf2-config --ldflags` `otf2-config --libs` test4.o
```

If you extend the upper command line, you would get:

```
mpic++ -fpic -c -I/usr/include -o test4.o test4.cpp
mpic++ -shared -o libtest4.so -L/usr/lib -lotf2 -lm test4.o
```

The intercepted MPI program is from [here](https://github.com/wesleykendall/mpitutorial/blob/gh-pages/tutorials/mpi-send-and-receive/code/send_recv.c).

Do interception:

```
$ mpirun -n 2 -x LD_PRELOAD=./libtest4.so ./send_recv
./send_recv: symbol lookup error: ./libtest4.so: undefined symbol: OTF2_Archive_Open
./send_recv: symbol lookup error: ./libtest4.so: undefined symbol: OTF2_Archive_Open
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[20246,1],0]
  Exit code:    127
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So it looks like mixing C and CPP causes problem. The linker couldn't correctly generate symbols for C function that is `OTF2_Archive_Open` and `OTF2_Archive_Close`.

I add 2 declarations to tell linker those are C functions(Download the modified program[here](https://pastebin.com/fLu2SvPh)):

```
_EXTERN_C_ OTF2_Archive* OTF2_Archive_Open ( const char *  archivePath,
const char *  archiveName,
const OTF2_FileMode   fileMode,
const uint64_t  chunkSizeEvents,
const uint64_t  chunkSizeDefs,
const OTF2_FileSubstrate  fileSubstrate,
const OTF2_Compression  compression
);
_EXTERN_C_ OTF2_ErrorCode OTF2_Archive_Close ( OTF2_Archive *  archive );
```

But the problem above stays. And advice?

**UPDATE1**:
OTF2 provides .a file, not .so file.

```
$ nm /usr/lib/libotf2.a| grep -i OTF2_Archive_Open
                 U otf2_archive_open
0000000000000000 T OTF2_Archive_Open
                 U otf2_archive_open_def_files
00000000000032e0 T OTF2_Archive_OpenDefFiles
                 U otf2_archive_open_evt_files
00000000000030e0 T OTF2_Archive_OpenEvtFiles
                 U otf2_archive_open_snap_files
00000000000034e0 T OTF2_Archive_OpenSnapFiles
                 U OTF2_Archive_Open
0000000000001180 T otf2_archive_open
0000000000005a40 T otf2_archive_open_def_files
                 U OTF2_Archive_OpenDefFiles
0000000000005880 T otf2_archive_open_evt_files
                 U OTF2_Archive_OpenEvtFiles
0000000000005c00 T otf2_archive_open_snap_files
                 U OTF2_Archive_OpenSnapFiles


$ ldd ./libtest4.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe3a6ce000)
    libmpi_cxx.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmpi_cxx.so.1 (0x00007f4757d67000)
    libmpi.so.12 => /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12 (0x00007f4757a91000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f475770e000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f47574f8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f475712e000)
    libibverbs.so.1 => /usr/lib/libibverbs.so.1 (0x00007f4756f1e000)
    libopen-rte.so.12 => /usr/lib/libopen-rte.so.12 (0x00007f4756ca4000)
    libopen-pal.so.13 => /usr/lib/libopen-pal.so.13 (0x00007f4756a07000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f47567e9000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f47564e0000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005620bef03000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f47562dc000)
    libhwloc.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhwloc.so.5 (0x00007f47560a1000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f4755e99000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f4755c96000)
    libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007f4755a8a000)
    libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f4755880000)



$ nm ./libtest4.so | grep -i OTF2_Archive_Open
                 U OTF2_Archive_Open
```

Weird is, I don't see any `libotf2.a` in the output of `ldd`. But if you try out the standard example of otf2 mpi writer from their website, it works out. And the output of `ldd` for the standard example of otf2 mpi writer doesn't contain `libotf2.a` either.

You could find the example [here](https://silc.zih.tu-dresden.de/otf2-current/group__usage__writing__mpi.html).

Comment: Note that identifiers beginning with an underscore followed by an
uppercase letter are reserved.

Comment: So, where is this symbol supposed to be defined. I don't see you linking any external libraries to the test4

Comment: Please add the outputs of `ldd ./libtest4.so`, `nm ./libtest4.so | grep -i OTF2_Archive_Open`, `nm libotf2.so | grep -i OTF2_Archive_Open`. You can also add `-x LD_DEBUG=all` to the mpi call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of linking matters. You must have your own library in front of the libraries you link, e.g.

```
mpic++ -shared test4.o -o libtest4.so `otf2-config --ldflags` `otf2-config --libs`
```

The linker resolves unknown symbols from left to right. For more details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409470/620382).
That will probably still not work if `otf2.a` isn't built with `-fPIC`. I would recommend to configure otf2 with `--enable-shared` and use the `.so` instead.